# File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg

Tags: errors, tufte

I'm creating my thesis using the Tufte template. I have this problem by compiling the main file:

```
riga 184: File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg. \input{./capitoli/personaggi}
: shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
: No file main.bbl.
riga 4: Overfull \hbox (11.77975pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 6: Overfull \hbox (9.91988pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 6: Overfull \hbox (10.11984pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 6: Overfull \hbox (14.14986pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 7: Overfull \hbox (16.93987pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 10: Overfull \hbox (41.9698pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 14: Citation `DavidHand_PrinciplesOfDataMining' undefined
: Marginpar on page 11 moved.
riga 23: Citation `ColinWare_InformationVisualization' undefined
: Marginpar on page 12 moved.
: Marginpar on page 12 moved.
riga 26: Citation `NathanShedroff_InformationInteractionDesign' undefined
: Marginpar on page 12 moved.
riga 31: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
riga 52: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
: Marginpar on page 14 moved.
riga 70: Citation `ChaomeiChen_Top10UnsolvedInformationVisualizationProblems' undefined
: Marginpar on page 14 moved.
: Marginpar on page 14 moved.
riga 7: Overfull \hbox (2.17984pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 13: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
riga 13: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
: Marginpar on page 16 moved.
riga 29: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
riga 3: Citation `DonaldNorman_ThingsThatMakeUsSmart' undefined
: Marginpar on page 17 moved.
riga 11: Citation `StuartCard_ReadingsInInformationVisualization' undefined
: Marginpar on page 17 moved.
riga 13: Font shape `T1/pplj/bx/sc' undefined(Font) using `T1/pplj/bx/n' instead
: Marginpar on page 17 moved.
riga 34: Citation `UsabilityFirst' undefined
: Marginpar on page 18 moved.
riga 5: Overfull \hbox (12.81596pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 6: Citation `Tufte_TheVisualDisplayOfQuantitativeInformation' undefined
riga 6: Citation `Tufte_EnvisioningInformation' undefined
riga 6: Citation `Tufte_BeautifulEvidence' undefined
riga 6: Citation `Tufte_VisualExplanations' undefined
: Marginpar on page 21 moved.
riga 11: Citation `Tufte_TheVisualDisplayOfQuantitativeInformation' undefined
: Marginpar on page 21 moved.
: destination with the same identifier (name{cite.Tufte_TheVisualDisplayOfQuantitativeInformation}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
riga 27: Overfull \hbox (12.56395pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 37: Citation `ColinWare_InformationVisualization' undefined
: destination with the same identifier (name{cite.ColinWare_InformationVisualization}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.37 ...e\cite{ColinWare_InformationVisualization} definisce il processo di ...
: Marginpar on page 22 moved.
riga 49: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
riga 61: Citation `BenFry_VisualizingData' undefined
: Marginpar on page 23 moved.
riga 129: Overfull \hbox (19.9498pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 146: Citation `ColinWare_VisualThinking' undefined
: Marginpar on page 28 moved.
riga 152: Citation `ColinWare_InformationVisualization' undefined
: destination with the same identifier (name{cite.ColinWare_InformationVisualization}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.152 ...\cite{ColinWare_InformationVisualization} definisce 4 proprietà pr...
: Marginpar on page 28 moved.
riga 174: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
riga 186: Overfull \hbox (37.95972pt too wide) in paragraph
: No file main.bbl.
: There were undefined citations.
: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

I don't understand what is due. Maybe there are too many images?

Here is the main file **main.tex**:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% per frontespizio
\usepackage[nouppercase, swapnames]{frontespizio}

% uncomment this line if you prefer colored hyperlinks (e.g., for onscreen viewing)
\hypersetup{colorlinks} 

% get chapter and section numbers {is the depth} (chapter, section, subsection)
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Book metadata
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{A Tufte-Style Book\thanks{Thanks to Edward R.~Tufte for his inspiration.}}
\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers}
\publisher{Publisher of This Book}

%\usepackage{microtype}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Just some sample text
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For nicely typeset tabular material
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For graphics/images
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, totalheight=\textheight, keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The fancyvrb package lets us customize the 
% formatting of verbatim environments.  
% We use a slightly smaller font.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prints argument within hanging parentheses (i.e., parentheses that take
% up no horizontal space).  Useful in tabular environments.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\hangp}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{(}#1\makebox[0pt][l]{)}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prints an asterisk that takes up no horizontal space.
% Useful in tabular environments.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\hangstar}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prints a trailing space in a smart way.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xspace}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Some shortcuts for Tufte's book titles.  
% The lowercase commands will produce the initials of the book title in italics.  
% The all-caps commands will print out the full title of the book in italics.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}

\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prints the month name (e.g., January) and the year (e.g., 2008)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\monthyear}{ 
  \ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or
  December\fi\space\number\year
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prints an epigraph and speaker in sans serif, all-caps type.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \sffamily\large
  \begin{doublespace}
  \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\ % epigraph
  \noindent\allcaps{#2} % author
  \end{doublespace}
  \end{fullwidth}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Inserts a blank page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}

\usepackage{units}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Typesets the font size, leading, and measure in the form of 10/12x26 pc.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\measure}[3]{#1/#2$\times$\unit[#3]{pc}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Macros for typesetting the documentation
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}} % prints in red
\newcommand{\hangleft}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}}
\newcommand{\hairsp}{\hspace{1pt}} % hair space
\newcommand{\hquad}{\hskip0.5em\relax} % half quad space
\newcommand{\TODO}{\textcolor{red}{\bf TODO!}\xspace}
\newcommand{\na}{\quad--} % used in tables for N/A cells
\providecommand{\XeLaTeX}{X\lower.5ex\hbox{\kern-0.15em\reflectbox{E}}\kern-0.1em\LaTeX}
\newcommand{\tXeLaTeX}{\XeLaTeX\index{XeLaTeX@\protect\XeLaTeX}}
\newcommand{\tuftebs}{\symbol{'134}} % a backslash in tt type in OT1/T1
\newcommand{\doccmdnoindex}[2][]{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}} % command name -- adds backslash automatically (and doesn't add cmd to the index)
\newcommand{\doccmddef}[2][]{
  \hlred{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}\label{cmd:#2}
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    { % add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}} % command name
    }
    { % add the command and package to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% command name
      \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}} % package name
    }
} 
% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\doccmd}[2][]{
  \texttt{\tuftebs#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    { % add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}} % command name
    }
    { % add the command and package to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)} % command name
      \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}} % package name
    }
} 
% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}} % optional command argument
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}} % (required) command argument
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quotation}\ttfamily\parskip0pt\parindent0pt\ignorespaces}{\end{quotation}} 
% command specification environment
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}} % environment name
\newcommand{\docenvdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{env:#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}} % environment name
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}} % package name
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % document class name
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}} % document class option name
\newcommand{\docclsoptdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{clsopt:#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}} % document class option name defined
\newcommand{\docmsg}[2]{\bigskip\begin{fullwidth}\noindent\ttfamily#1\end{fullwidth}\medskip\par\noindent#2}
\newcommand{\docfilehook}[2]{\texttt{#1}\index{file hooks!#2}\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccounter}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 counter@\texttt{#1} counter}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Generates the index
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

    % frontespizio
    \frontmatter
    %\input{./frontespizio/frontespizio} % copertina
    \input{./ringraziamenti/ringraziamenti} % ringraziamenti
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables   

    % corpo della tesi
    \mainmatter
    \input{./capitoli/abstract}
    \input{./capitoli/introduzione}
    \input{./capitoli/personaggi}

    % bibliografia
    \backmatter
    \bibliography{./bibliografia/bibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

    %\printindex
\end{document}
```

And a piece of the file that generates the error is **personaggi.tex**:

```
\chapter{Personaggi chiave nella storia della data visualization}
Si è soliti pensare che i grafici statistici e la data visualization siano stati sviluppati in epoca moderna ma in realtà la rappresentazione grafica di informazioni quantitative ha radici profonde. 

%********************************************************************%

\section{Prima del XVII secolo: mappe e diagrammi} % ...-1600
Le prime visualizzazioni riguardano corpi celesti e mappe geografiche che potevano aiutare i commercianti ed i navigatori durante i propri viaggi.

  \subsection{Posizione del sole, della luna e delle stelle (950 a.C.)}
    L'affascinante diagramma in figura ~\ref{fig:unk-planetary} ricorda una moderna data visualization poiché utilizza un sistema a griglia per combinare sia il tempo che la posizione dei corpi planetari. Il suo significato esatto, così come il suo autore, non si conosce,  ma l'asse verticale è suddiviso in 12 parti che rappresentano lo zodiaco mentre l'asse orizzontale è suddiviso in 30 parti, ognuna delle quali indica un'unità di tempo. Il moto dei pianeti è invece rappresentato con sinusoidi che si intersecano tra di loro.

    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics{./img/unk-planetary.png}
      \caption[][6pt]{Il disegno mostra il movimento ciclico dei sette più grandi corpi celesti (a sinistra) osservabili dalla Terra. Questo diagramma compare a corredo alle glosse di A. T. Macrobius all’opera di Cicerone \textit{In somnium Scripionus}.}
      \label{fig:unk-planetary}
    \end{figure}

%********************************************************************%

\section{XVII secolo: misurazioni e teoria} % 1600-1700
I problemi più importati nel XVII secolo legati all'astronomia, la navigazione e l'esplorazione erano la misurazione del tempo, della distanza e dello spazio.

  \subsection{Christopher Scheiner (1573-1650)}
    Christopher Scheiner è stato un astronomo e matematico tedesco.
    Nel 1630 realizza una visualizzazione (figura~\ref{fig:Scheiner-sunspot}) che mostra 37 piccole immagini di lune, ognuna con macchie differenti a seconda di quali sono visibili dalla Terra nel corso dell'anno (il periodo temporale va dal 23 ottobre ak 19 dicembre 1611). Tufte chiama quest'idea \textit{principio delle small multiples}\sidenote{Si deve a Tufte l'invenzione del termine \textit{small multiple} per riferirsi a rappresentazioni multiple di immagini comparabili tra loro, così da permettere un facile confronto.}.
    %\cite{Tufte_TheVisualDisplayOfQuantitativeInformation}

    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics{./img/Scheiner-sunspot.png}
      \caption[][6pt]{\textit{Tres epistolae de maculis solaribus} (1630) di Christopher Scheiner.}
      \label{fig:Scheiner-sunspot}
    \end{figure}
```

I looked on the internet but I didn't find anything that would help me solve the problem. What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know; but the most likely source of the problem is a command input (either {} or []) that has been omitted or not closed at some earlier point in the file. If it's a "long" command, then it could be much earlier! These can be hard to track down. Unless you've recently added something (which is likely the culprit) I'd put `\end{document}` at various points and recompile, moving them backwards until it will compile. At that point you have a fair idea of where to look. It may be considerably earlier than the point where the error is being reported.